# Is "List" specially handled in Haskell's pattern matching?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am a newbie in Haskell and hope this question is not silly.

I have seen so much example that when I am having a list, I am able to match and bind "composition element" of the list to individual variable:

```
listSizeDesc :: [a] -> String
listSizeDesc [] = "Emtpy"
listSizeDesc (x:xs) = "Something inside"
```

However, I tried to do something like:

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo 0 = "Zero"
foo (n - 1) = "next number is " ++ show n
```

It doesn't work.

It seems to me that both (n-1) and (x:xs) describe how the argument is "created" and bind the "component" to an argument.  Is the way List matched specially designed for ease of recursion?  Coz it seems to me this matching / argument-binding logic doesn't apply to other functions except (:).

Comment: Definitely not a stupid question. This is my understanding as a fellow newbie: lists are not "special". Pattern matching works with : because : is a type constructor for lists. It works type constructors but not for general functions. How this work is explained quite well [here on WikiBooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching)

Comment: There is no such thing as a silly question, as long as it is well asked.

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: Just to avoid confusion: The proper term here is “data constructor”. A “type constructor” would be, for example, `Maybe`.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner thanks. I can't edit my comment and can only upvote your comment to try and make it more visible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The list type is "Sum type" with a constructor, something like:

```
data List a =
     cons a (List a)
   | nil
```

You first example is a pattern match on a datatype (with syntactic sugar for  `:`).

Your second example is a pattern match on integers, which are not a datatypye definition. On integer, there is no pattern using your syntax. You may write your example with:

```
foo :: Int -> String
foo 0 = "Zero"
foo n = "next number is " ++ show (n+1)
```

On a side note if you encode integers with datatypes like:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat deriving (Show)
```

Then you can use your pattern match as you wanted initially.

```
foo :: Nat -> String
foo Zero = "Zero"
foo n@Succ(p) = "next number is " ++ show(n)
```

Here the pattern `Succ(p)` plays the role of `n-1`.

Comment: Great examples! Everything makes sense to me now  :D  Thanks a lot

Comment: That last example is backwards.  In order to match what the OP wants, the pattern should just be `n` and the function should show `Succ n`.

Answer (score 18):

The problem you're encountering is that pattern matching only works with data constructors. A data constructor is in essence very simple; it just takes data values and groups them together in some sort of structure. For example, `data Foo = Bar a b` simply takes two pieces of data and groups them together under the Foo label. The `(:)` function you use in your first example is more than just a function; it's a data constructor. It constructs a new list by adding the left argument to the right argument.

Now, pattern matching is merely doing the opposite of this process. It deconstructs a datatype. When you write `(x:xs)` in your pattern, you're extracting the two pieces of data that the constructor originally stitched together. So all pattern matching does is extract the data that a constructor previously stitched together.

There is one exception: n+k patterns. In Haskell98, you were allowed to use patterns of the form (n+k). This was sort of an arbitrary exception and it was recently removed. If you'd like, you can still use it if you include the NPlusKPatterns language pragma.

Comment: Great answer.  Though I gave the "Accept" to another answer due to the intuitive example given, this answer is doubtless as great.  I wish I can accept 2 answers at the same time coz I think both answers are good compliments to each other.

Answer (score 5):

There are already some great answers, so I won't bother with the main question. This is *not* the best use of it, but what you were trying to do can sort of be accomplished with [view patterns](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

foo :: Int -> String
foo 0 = "Zero"
foo (pred -> n) = "Next number is " ++ show n
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to put it as simply as possible:
A list *literally is* a series of concatenations. A number *could be equivalent to* the result of an arithmetic operation. The difference is that the result of `a : b` is simply `a : b`.

---

In more detail:

Lists and (:) aren't a special case at all. Let's make our own:

```
data List2 a = End               -- equivalent of "[]"
             | Cat a (List2 a)   -- non-infix ":"
  deriving (Show)
```

So `[1, 2, 3]`, which == `(1 : (2 : (3 : [])))`, would be written as:

```
a = Cat 1 (Cat 2 (Cat 3 End))
```

Just like pattern-matching `(x:xs)`, we can pattern-match List2:

```
newTail End = End
newTail (Cat _ x) = x
```

Test it:

```
*Main> tail [1,2,3]
[2,3]
*Main> newTail a
Cat 2 (Cat 3 End)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
moo :: Int -> String
moo 0 = "Zero"
moo n = "next number is " ++ show (n + 1)
```

`n - 1` is an ordinary function application, not a pattern.  An exception used to be made for `+` and this might be the model you are going by.  You can write something like

```
goo :: Int -> String
goo 0 = "Zero"
goo (n+1)  = "previous number is " ++ show n
```

in `hugs` ; you still can do this with the `ghc`, if you include the pragma

```
{-#LANGUAGE NPlusKPatterns#-}
```

Comment: BTW, those `NPlusKPatterns` are deprecated, as they confuse many programmers. Use with care! Also, AFAIK they only match positive numbers.